# Image Map links not working on iOS device

Tags: ios, css, html

I am making an xmas e-card, the powers that be wanted an animated "movie" that would have links at the end. And they want it work work on EVERY DEVICE IMAGINABLE. I used "easyhtml5video" to convert my After Effects mp4 and write the javascript. I then put a transparent image over the video that has some image maps with links, using z-index. It works great in all browsers, but the links do NOT work on iOS devices. The video controls pop up when I try to click the link area. ideas?

Comment: You may be having problems with `position:fixed` on the iOS devices. Would need to see code for anything else.

Answer (score 0):

You can try http://tumult.com/hype/ for creating interactive content for a wide range of devices. Also tell your client that almost nothing is available for every device imaginable ;-)